# Unable to access phpmyadmin after redirecting the tomcat port number

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, phpmyadmin, centos7

I am working on centos for first time. I have installed tomcat which loads on port 8080 `http://my_ip:8080/`. I have also installed apache phpmyadmin which loads on `http://my_ip/`. I am able to access **phpmyadmin sql** through the url `http://my_ip/phpmyadmin`.

Everythng works fine.  But I want to redirect my tomcat port from 8080 to 80. I used the following command `sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`.

After running the command I am able to open tomcat on `http://my_ip` with out using port. but the problem is when I try to access phpmyadmin sql  `http://my_ip/phpmyadmin` It gives me 404 error not found. I dont know where I am going wrong how can I access tomcat and phpmyadmin sql both.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting 80 TO 8080. And as on your second tomcat you dont have any "phpmyadmin" context, you get a 404